# What to do with Typescript Function Overload Growth with Optional Variables

Tags: typescript, overloading, return-type

I'm having a hard time looking for a solution to deal with the exponential growth of function overloads in typescript, here's the problem:

Say I have a findOne function that gets an id, looks in the database, and finds a Person:

```
findOne(id):Promise<Person| undefined> {
    return query().findById(id);
}
```

Now I can have a variable added to throw if Person is not found (id does not exist) and make sure that findOne is not returning undefined if the variable is passed;

```
findOne(id):Promise<Person|undefined>;
findOne(id,orFail:true):Promise<Person>;
findOne(id,orFail?:true):Promise<Person|undefined> {
    if (orFail){
        return query().findById(id).throwIfNotFound();
    }
    return query().findById(id);
}
```

Now, what happens if I have another variable that decides if a field of person should be joined or not? yes, it multiplies the return types by 2 (adding another possibility for each previous one to have a joined field or not)

Again, If I have more variables, each one will multiply it by 2, so I think I will have `2^optionalVarialesCount` overloads of the findOne function.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to overload 16 times for 4 optional variables, It really makes the code messy.

Comment: If you have multiple options that change the return type of the overloaded function, I think you're trying to do too much with one function. I mean, yes, there are APIs out there that have 30+ overloads (usually because they were JavaScript APIs and then the TypeScript types were added later and had to accommodate the wild west of original JavaScript :-D ). If you really want to have multiple options that have an effect on the return type, I don't think there's any getting around having an explosion of overloads, which is hard to write, read, use, and maintain. Since the options ...

Comment: ...would have to be hardcoded anyway to make the return type different, I'd suggest trying to group them together and having X functions with Y overloads each, that kind of thing. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I myself reached the same conclusion, but hoped to missed some trick with Generics or some other thing maybe, so asked here. Thanks by the way

Comment: Yeah, it's a good question to ask. TypeScript is so rich, I often see solutions to things I wouldn't think it could solve. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all let's define optional props as a tuple:

```js
type Optional = [onFail: true, onPass: false]
```

You can define any number of props you want in `Optional` tuple.

Now we can overload our function:

```js
type Person = {
  tag: 'Person'
}

type Optional = [onFail: true, onPass: false]

function findOne<
  /**
   * Infer rest arguments
   */
  Rest extends Partial<Optional>,
  /**
   * 1) if length of Rest arguments extends length of Optional arguments
   * it means that all Optional arguments was provided, which in tirn means that
   * we should return Promise<Person>
   * 
   * 2) otherwise, if Rest length is less then Optional length, it means
   * that no all Optional arguments was passes, which in turn means
   * that we should return Promise<Person | undefined>
   */
  Return extends {
    all_passed: Promise<Person>,
    not_all_passed: Promise<Person | undefined>,
  }[
  Rest['length'] extends Optional['length'] ? 'all_passed' : 'not_all_passed'
  ]
>(id: string, ...args: Rest): Return

function findOne(id: string, ...args: Partial<Optional>): Promise<Person | undefined> {
  return null as any
}

// Promise<Person | undefined> because not optional arguments are passed
const _ = findOne('id', true) 

// Promise<Person> because all optional arguments are passed
const __ = findOne('id', true, false)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwLACgopgBDAcwC4oByOJNaggXwINEigHkxgBLNEgBtMUANpoAYiV6CqweAFcIAGihoYJRIioAzIYggBdVvh0LUAYz5ooO3qgAmnVBAA8BIgHoAVN49FvKABJVB0EKHgIRGAoEngyBQBbCFRgRH8ob09-ACUomIgAD2AUh0RYOL4hV25rVCEAPmV-Hz9CAKgARgBKKF4dKEEUsmAACzUBvOjY%20KSUtKgiksdyodQR8eQB2v564TiE5NT09sy%20mOSSVHKxkhihYR2BfdmjhYB3TSgweGQAN14DggDlU71GvAs43sxF48HQl2uxFGdwygXe0EQo2QCkEDgiEGACjhsF%20iV4BlcdBQqAaqKgdIATL1kGMEO9ySo%20pN8oNhmM%20qsojdRikuDxdkJeesxqpeBcIFcTkQzrcYqhkLFBI9xc8Zod5uVPuUwJoDIhQeDIX10ITiQilR1VVB0VBMdjcfjbegYKSOZSENSoAAfKDmIF2FwOWmnLK5AlE9BLUrlPCnTWCAD6Jq0wKoPuQZIpVLQTQyUHVwAzDyzptzJILfuL6BDYYgEeBpfaTFEceiomoaw21EMi2KybFdSE-cHY2HUAA-DRq9mDA5qFAqNQK1WtTWc2v-MZ8A0ABSAqjReD2MiqAB094O2igU2A3SoeS9JjMljqtnsThcM8HAveRrzvB94ifDR4CqQQah1PYGjfetCzcJtg1DRw23sDscH8SIvXLHF9nKK4QGYExPE8FDGwDGwWyw9soygAAjCALBIBQDHLFk1AQyUDjmY4ZmgFdgQICw0GmDMRAjACIBPahAWoVR5CUXpKOo-NUP9egaVY9jOO4h4%20MnF59WEuJRNrBwJKkmIMxkrA5OcBSlLXVTFE5PRBAMXogA)